# CentOS7 Virtual Machine postgres10 not initializing

Tags: postgresql, centos

I had postgres9.6 installed and working the other day but the version wasn't compatible.

I used YUM REMOVE to remove that one and then followed the instructions here 
https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/
to install postgres10.

However anytime I do the

```
/usr/pgsql-10/bin/postgresql-10-setup initdb
```

it returns

```
Initializing database ... mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/lib/pgsql’: Permission denied
```

Initializing database ... failed, see /var/lib/pgsql/10/initdb.log

However the log file is actually empty.

I've tried a number of things suggested with no success. Any advice would be great as to where to start looking about this

Comment: I think the error message is self-explanatory -- the postgres user cannot create a directory under `/var/lib` (which is normal). Create one and give it proper ownership.

Comment: You need to run that as `root`